# HTML number of rows variables on MySQL column value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to make a query that sets the rows (number of weeks) depending on the number of weeks the instructor wants the clinical to go, this value is stored in a Mysql table called clinical with a column name weeks (int). Right now in my HTML I have just pasted 4 rows to get the look down. I realize I will need to make a connection to the db before this code

```
<table width="1000" border="1">
<tr>
    <td colspan="8" style="background-color:#1589FF;text-align:center;">
    <h1>Rating for the Week</h1>
    </td>
<tr>
    <th>Week</th>
    <th>Faculty Signature</th>
    <th>Rating for the Week <br>
        S+/S/NI/U</th>
    <th>Student Signature</th>
    <th>Rating for the Week <br>
        S+/S/NI/U</th>

</tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ALIGN="CENTER">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><form><input type = "submit" /></form></td> 
    <td><select>
        <option value="S+">S+</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="NI">NI</option>
        <option value="U">U</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><form><input type = "submit" /></form></td>
    <td><select>
        <option value="S+">S+</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="NI">NI</option>
        <option value="U">U</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ALIGN="CENTER">
    <td>2</td>
    <td><form><input type = "submit" /></form></td> 
    <td><select>
        <option value="S+">S+</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="NI">NI</option>
        <option value="U">U</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><form><input type = "submit" /></form></td>
    <td><select>
        <option value="S+">S+</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="NI">NI</option>
        <option value="U">U</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ALIGN="CENTER">
    <td>3</td>
    <td><form><input type = "submit" /></form></td> 
    <td><select>
        <option value="S+">S+</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="NI">NI</option>
        <option value="U">U</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><form><input type = "submit" /></form></td>
    <td><select>
        <option value="S+">S+</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="NI">NI</option>
        <option value="U">U</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tr ALIGN="CENTER">
    <td>4</td>
    <td><form><input type = "submit" /></form></td> 
    <td><select>
        <option value="S+">S+</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="NI">NI</option>
        <option value="U">U</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><form><input type = "submit" /></form></td>
    <td><select>
        <option value="S+">S+</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="NI">NI</option>
        <option value="U">U</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="8" style="background-color:#1589FF;text-align:center;">
    <b> The student must pass the clinical component of the course which is        ted on a pass/fail basis.<br>
    A clinical failure results in a grade of F for the course.<b>
    </td>
</tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: About what programming language are you working?

Comment: @jclandero23 the question is tagged with `php`.

Answer (score 0):

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT weeks FROM `clinical` WHERE clinicname = $clinicname
```

The query will select the column `weeks` from the table `clinical`
I added the WHERE statement because if there are multiple clinics it would choose the appropriate one, as long as you have the column `clinicname` included in your table.
To make a row for each week you would create a while loop like so:

```
<?php 
$number_of_weeks_from_query = $query_result;
$i = 0;
while($i < $number_of_weeks_from_query){

INSERT EACH ROW TEMPLATE HERE AND CHANGE THE WEEK NUMBER TO $i

$i++;
}
?>
```

I would suggest using Mysql PDO as the old MySql functions will be deprecated very soon. I would also suggest to use AJAX so you can keep the page loaded when someone hits the submit button. Please tell me if I did anything wrong, my PHP is still rusty.

Comment: You'll want to use a prepared statement to protect against SQL injection assuming the user has control over the $clinicname input.

Comment: Were would this code go? Would it go where I have "1"? or should I make a dynamic table in PHP? Which is better?

Comment: Instead of having the rows (the 4 pasted rows)where a user can change the grades put that code in that portion of the table. Put one of those pasted rows in the "INSERT EACH ROW TEMPLATE HERE" part. Using an echo statement. I would change all the "" in the row template to ''. I suggest reading up on while loops as they are fundamental in php.